# Preventing Apex Button Double click

Tags: javascript, sql, oracle, oracle-apex

Hi I have a button that inserts empty records into an interactive grid. I want to prevent the user from being able to double click that button because it populates duplicate rows. I have a server side argument that says if there are rows the button does not appear however they are still able to double click the Populate_tables button before it vanishes. If there are any other solutions to this please sound off. I've tried everything from javascript to server-side but they are still able to double click no matter what. Here are the before and after pictures of the table. [image: Before Double click]

[image: After Double Click]

Comment: perhaps you can create a dummy_button with the same label. with a DA you can hide the real button and set dummy_button's visibility to YES. and raise a message to notify them when they click on this dummy button.

Comment: Depending on the situation, I add an action to my DA that hides the triggering element, so the button disappears after click (or you can disable it)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
    $('#btnPopulateTbl').dblclick(function(e){ 
         e.preventDefault();
    });
```

The above code prevents the double click for a button. This is in jQuery.

Comment: Thanks I had tried to implement something like this earlier but am not super familiar with Java this worked like a charm.

Comment: This is jQuery and you can elaborate more so that anyone who knows the answer will probably post it.

Answer (score 2):

Oracle Apex does not offer this functionality as a setting or etc.
However you can use

```
$('#button').click(function(event) {
  if(!event.detail || event.detail == 1){
   // This will be executed once even user clicks multiple times
  }
});
```

Note that your selector must be the id or the class you provide to this button.
By default 'add row' button's classes are:

```
class="a-Button a-Toolbar-item js-actionButton"
```

Answer (score 2):

Another solution would be to have apex handle this. Suppose this is on page 1.

- Create a page item P1_POPULATE_ROWS_CLICKED with a default value of 'N'
- In the page process that populates the table, add the following line before the actual load:

```
:P1_POPULATE_ROWS_CLICKED := 'Y';
```

- Add a condition to the page process that populates the table of "Item not equal to value", P1_POPULATE_ROWS_CLICKED , Y

Yet another solution is to only execute the insert statement if no rows exist with that condition yet. I can't show you how to do it because you didn't show ***how*** the table is populated but happy to do so if you edit your question. This last option is propably the most suitable.

Comment: This is a bit round about for what I want to do and makes more work for the user. Thanks for the suggestion!